Explicit subsequence of $(\sin n )$
The existence of a subsequence of the sequence $(\sin n)$ coming from the Bolzano Weierstrass theorem ,as we know any infinite bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. But I can't find such subsequence in an explicit form. Any help will be appreciated.

I believe it's also a theorem that the image of that particular sequence is dense in $[-1, 1]$.

Take $\varphi (n) = \lbrace 2 \pi n , \pi / 2 + 2 \pi n  , 3\pi / 2 + 2 \pi n \rbrace$  for example

The set of $m+2\pi n$ is dense on the real line. Consequently the points $e^{in}$ are dense on the unit circle in the complex plane and thus also $\sin(n)$ dense on the interval $[-1,1]$. So there exist sub-sequences for any point in that interval that converge to that point.

@Ceru Is it a subsequence? Can you elaborate?

@LutzLehmann Yes but what is that subsequence? Is there any closed form? That's what my question is.
